# VNC viewer gets not connected after update of Remote desktop client

Tags: ios, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan, vnc-viewer

VNC viewer not connects after updation of "remote desktop client update version 3.8.5" from 22-03-2016 onwards.I am using "VNC 5.0.1"

1.This is the error shows when I connect VNC viewer.

[image]

2.This Screen shot shows the Image of update details.Remote desktop update got auto-update last evening.After,that If I connect through VNC. It shows the error message of 1st Image.

[image]

I have two apple id accounts.One account access directly through Mac mini and another one is access through VNC viewer.It works fine before the "remote desktop update".

I go through this link:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7501620?start=0&tstart=0.

Now, I suggested to update my OS X "yosemite" to "El Capitan".If I do this,The problem will be solved.Or Any other solution for this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @downvoter If you don't know the answer keep idle ...others will response

Comment: please anyone faced this issue...what's the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, just update to El Capitain.

We got this problem yesterday too, after update the "Remote Desktop Client Update" on our iMac with Yosemite, "the Security Update 2016-002" wans't installed yet.
We just finished to update to El Capitain and is all working fine again.

Remember to create a backup before update, just to be sure.

Comment: I posted the answer there too: https://discussions.apple.com/message/29956459#29956459

Comment: Do you use this mac to develop on Xcode? Using VNC I can't create segue ways or IBOutlets using Control + click, or move views inside the storyboard. Do you have this problem too?

Comment: yeah bro....connecting directly with mac only works properly....if you connect through vnc there should be a problem....1.you can't move the storyboard  2.we can create segue and iboutlets by right click the mouse...instead of Ctrl click 3.then for auto layouts if you click ctrl drag...can't done through vnc.